# Rails request return status 200 but no response data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, nginx

I have a rails action as below:

```
def create
  ......
  if @course.save
    render json: { success: true, course: @course.info}
  else
    render json: { success: false, error_msg: @course.errors.full_messages }
  end
```

the request return status 200 but no response data.

[image]
[image]

the nginx log and rails log looks normal:

```
# nginx log
100.116.224.40 [14/Aug/2018:18:59:12 +0800] POST "xxxxx" 200 200 27 
"47.88.138.112" xxx

# rails log
method=POST path=xxxxformat=*/* controller=xxxx action=create 
status=200 duration=45.94 view=0.23 params=
```

Comment: @Gabbar Thanks for response!, I have tried but still doesn't work!

Comment: Have you tried byebug just below your if statement? What is the value of @course.info?

Comment: @course.info is a  hash, if I remove it, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since course is presumably a hash, try `course["info"]`

if that still isn't working, you may need to convert the info hash to JSON using `JSON.parse(course["info"])`